# How to Improve quality of OCR text in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ocr

I am having an example of OCR from github. But quality of text is very low. How to improve text quality....please help me soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHat have you tried ? E.g. have you tried using morphological operators to make the text more solid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you be able to afford a commercial OCR engine on iPhone, such as [ABBYY](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileOCR)? Otherwise, server-side OCR is always an option if the user does not mind the delay. It has an added advantage that you can peek into your user's images - but tread carefully - don't break laws and make sure your user license conveys what you're going to do with those images.